# if else statement is not working as intended

Tags: php, if-statement

Im trying to filter sorts of bicycles
ladies, men, children. 
i wrote a function which sorts our a string of numbers to the selected sort of bicycle.

```
function: bicycle($stringnumbers, $sortbicycle)
```

script:

```
    function bicycle($stringnumbers, $sortbicycle){
    $bicycle = explode(',', $bicyclenumbers);
    foreach($bicycle as $bicycle1)
    {
       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `bicycle` WHERE `bicyclenumber` LIKE '".$bicycle1."' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
       $number = mysql_query($sql2)or die(mysql_error());
       while ($bicycleinfo = mysql_fetch_array($number)) 
       {
          $number1 = $bicycleinfo['sortbicycle'];
          if($sortbicycle == "kid") 
          {
             if($number1 == "boy")
             {
                $totaal .= "J " . $bicycle1 . ",";
             }
             elseif($number1 == "girl")
             {
                $totaal .= "M " . $bicycle1 . ",";
             }      
          }
          elseif($sortbicycle == "kids") 
          {
             if ($number1 == "boy")
             {
                $totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
             }
             elseif($number1 == "girl")
             {
                $totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
             }      
          }
          elseif($number1 == $sortbicycle)
          {
             $totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
          }
       }
    }

    if($totaal > "1")
    {
       $amount1 = $total;
    }
    else
    {
       $amount1 = ""; 
    }

 return $amount1;   
 }
```

but for some reason this part:

```
    if ($number1 == "boy")
    {
       $totaal .= "J " . $bicycle1 . ",";
    }
    elseif ($number1 == "girl")
    {
       $totaal .= "M " . $bicycle1 . ",";
    }               
 }
 elseif ($sortbicycle == "kids") 
 {
    if ($number1 == "boy")
    {
       $totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
    }
    elseif ($number1 == "girl")
    {
       $totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
    }           
 }
```

is not working as it should, the first part the "kid" part works but when i remove the

```
$totaal .= "J " . $bicycle1 . ",";
```

to

```
$totaal .= $bicycle1 . ",";
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: And what happens when you change the code? (You've left us hanging there...)

Comment: Add in some debugging code, so you can see what inputs your code is dealing with and make sure that the right part of the `if` statement is being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

One observation is that you refer to both `$totaal` and `$total`, and you return `$amount1` that is in no way affected by `$totaal`. Unless `$totaal` is a global variable, it won't be used.

Comment: input should look like: bicycle("9,6,32", "kid")

then the output would be: J 9,M6,

input 2 should look like: bicycle("9,6,32", "kids")

then the output would be: 9,6,

but now there is no output at all when i type "kids"
also when i switch "kid" with "kids" so the both if and elseif statement the upper one just works. the output is nothing now as it should give 9,6,

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed this:

```
function bicycle($stringnumbers, $sortbicycle){
$bicycle = explode(',', $bicyclenumbers);
```

In your function the input is $stringnumbers but you don't use it anywhere in your code.
Instead you use $bicylenumbers, shoudn't that be $stringnumbers?